# Is your communication in same subnet safe when an attacker initiates a ARP Poisoning attack?

Tags: man-in-the-middle

Is it possible that the Man-In-The-Middle can eavesdrop on communications in your subnet? (meaning between computers in your subnet and not outside of it)

I am learning networking and I made this assumption from my course material and I'd like to double check.

Comment: Yes, purposefully putting yourself in the path of network traffic so that you can potentially change it is a way to eavesdrop on that communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an attacker on the same broadcast domain (in this case subnet) it is relatively easy to perform an ARP spoofing attack.

Within a broadcast domain TCP sequence prediction *style* attacks become much more valid if the attacker can simply listen for the sequence number in promiscuous mode instead of actually guessing it.

Comment: AFAIK, current modern systems have a low risk of guessing TCP sequence numbers. Also, is it possible for the attacker to eavesdrop or not?

Comment: For guessing it is unlikely, but what if it were possible to just observe them? The TCP headers are not private on a lan...

Comment: The point of either attack is usually mitm

Comment: What does observing TCP sequence number give you away? AFAIK, it only gives away how many packets were sent.

Comment: Knowing the sequence number allows an attacker to send the next tcp packet instead of the victim... It basically allows for a TCP connection to be taken over. Look up a paper about sequence prediction, it is the same idea but the mitigations don't matter on a lan because it can be observed instead of guessed.

Comment: Could you give me a link about such a paper? My search on Google Scholar gave me no relevant results...

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the lab we did about it, it is the chapter about TCP session hijacking http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Book/book_sample_tcp.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the Man-In-The-Middle can eavesdrop on communications in your subnet?

Yes.

One option is to (attempt to) spoof the ARP entry for the network gateway, so that traffic flows through your malicious host rather than the legitimate gateway. 
This would (theoretically) allow you to eavesdrop on any non-encrypted traffic. 
You could also attempt to spoof DNS responses, to compel the target node(s) to send certain traffic through your host.
Similarly, you could attempt to run your own DHCP server (if that is in use in the subnet) to achieve something similar to spoofing the network gateway.

However, it is worth noting that this isn't a panacea: x509 and related technologies (like key pinning) can help mitigate the risk of such eavesdropping, as might the use of a VPN. This irrespective of whether you are able to spoof ARP or DHCP, assuming the VPN software/x509 code is sound.

tl;dr: you can certainly try and force one or more nodes in 'your' subnet to route their traffic (or a subset of their traffic) through a host of your choosing. Assuming nothing on the network prevents this, whether you can eavesdrop as a result of doing so will largely depend on what you want to eavesdrop, vs what protections are in place for the traffic (e.g. VPN, HTTPS, DNS-SEC).

Comment: this takes place in the local network (a.k.a same subnet). I don't quite see how VPN would help here.

Comment: I had meant that a VPN can largely mitigate a lot of the risks of MITM, to avoid ARP spoofing (and similar attacks) from resulting in _actual_ eavesdropping. In other words, being able to inject oneself into the traffic path doesn't necessarily result in the ability to (meaningfully) eavesdrop.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But here we're talking about communications in the same subnet without any remote communication.

Comment: I had understood the question a little differently (as not necessarily being limited to traffic _within_ the subnet). I think a VPN would still serve as a possible defense against eavesdropping irrespective of whether the traffic is within the same subnet or not, but I agree with you that in practice, it would be unusual to see VPNs being used in such circumstances.

Comment: I think a VPN would be completely useless in local communication to make it bold.